# Currency conversion formula

Tags: php, math, currency

I want to be able to convert from one currency to another, I found a XML API [here](http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml) which covers *most* of the currencies I use around my site, but the problem I'm experiencing is how to convert from one currency to another with this XML file.

Obviously I parsed and added the currencies and it's rates to an array like this:

```
Array 
(
    [USD] => 1.3412
    [JPY] => 107.99
    [BGN] => 1.9558
    ...
```

The formula to convert from an *exchanged* rate is this:

```
$from = 'GBP';  // The currency can be dynamic to a different currency
$to = 'USD';    // this one too

$amount = 400;
$converted_amount = round($amount / $rate, 2);
```

`$rate` is what I'm clueless onto what to do - how to convert into the exchange rate that will be able to be dividable to the `$amount`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can't you just multiply `$amount` by the exchange rate defined in your array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rates in this XML are actually euro-rates: i.e., EUR/USD, EUR/JPY, etc. So what you need is:

```
$from = 'USD'; 
$to   = 'JPY';
$amount = 100;

$conversion_rate  = $rates[$from] / $rates[$to];
$converted_amount = round ($amount / $conversion_rate, 2);
```

Comment: Ah, I see, I thought it was a different, complex formula. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If I may advice, I personally use this

```
http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/php-currency-conversion-exchange-rates-xml/
```

It's very simple, class that do all job for you

```
$x->convert(2.50,'FROM','TO');
```